# Oracle Index building/dropping history

Tags: oracle, ddl

Is there a Metadata table that logs the 'Create/Drop' index history?

I found the 'ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS' and 'ALL_TAB_STATS_HISTORY' tables, but they don't have index building logs.

Answer (score 3):

This is what AUDIT is for.
Start here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/AUDIT-Traditional-Auditing.html#GUID-ADF45B07-547A-4096-8144-50241FA2D8DD

-- Edit
And note that auditing is not retroactive.  It will not capture that which occurred before it was enabled.